# Tengo problema para subir una imagen, y no se que podrá ser

Tags: angularjs, laravel

Estoy usando angularjs y laravel... y asi esta mi formulario para subir un logo:

```
<label title="" for="logo">Logo:</label>
<input type="file" name="logo" file-model="identidad.logo" ng-model="identidad.logo" id="logo" required>
```

y en el controlador laravel:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $i = new Identidad();
    $i->direccion = $request->direccion;
    $i->club_id = auth()->user()->club->id;
    if (Input::hasFile('logo')){
        $file=Input::file('logo');
        $file->move(public_path().'/img/logos/', $file->getClientOriginalName());
        $i->logo=$file->getClientOriginalName();
    }
    $i->save();
    return $i;
}
```

La verdad no se cual pueda ser el problema.. porque uso ese mismo codigo en otro formulario para subir imagenes y los sube perfectamente!! en este formulario donde tengo el problema sube las otras cosas menos el logo, miren en la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por favor ayudaa!!

Answer (score 0):

Parece que estas usando una directiva file-model, por lo que se me ocurre que el problema es que ng-model apunta a la misma variable, por lo que seguramente la propiedad logo llega null al controlador.

Prueba de la siguiente manera:

```
<label title="" for="logo">Logo:</label>
<input type="file" name="logo" file-model="identidad.logo" id="logo" required />
```

Comment: nada, sigue sin subir la imagen :/ pero no entiendo si uso el mismo con otro formulario  y me sube la imagen perfectamente :/

Comment: serviria que mostraras los datos que se envian en la peticion.

Comment: como los muestros? me ayudas please!

Comment: En la consola del navegador ve a la parte de red, ahi puedes encontrar todos los valores que van en la peticion.

Comment: tu dices esto: 
 [{id: 4, logo: null, direccion: "Av. maturin", club_id: 1, created_at: "2017-08-30 23:55:23",…}]
0
:
{id: 4, logo: null, direccion: "Av. maturin", club_id: 1, created_at: "2017-08-30 23:55:23",…}
club
:
{id: 1, nombre: "Sol de Oriente", telefono: "923847356", categoria_id: 2, iglesia_id: 1, user_id: 4,…}
club_id
:
1
created_at
:
"2017-08-30 23:55:23"
direccion
:
"Av. maturin"
id
:
4
logo
:
null
updated_at
:
"2017-08-30 23:55:23"

Comment: Si me referia a eso, si puedes ver ahi el valor de logo es null, estas importando la directiva file-model?, porque es una libreria ajena al core de angularjs

Comment: sii, la estoy importando! q tiene q ver?? porq esa misma directiva me funciona en otro formulario :/